# How to have a number directly under a decimal point?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I am trying to write a number in quaternary form and would ideally like to show this by having a four underneath the decimal point. I've searched around, but can't figure out how to do this  so any help would be appreciated.
What I'm looking for:

[image]

Update: Thank you very much, excellent solutions. I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\basex}[3]{#2\separator{#1}#3}
\newcommand{\separator}[1]{%
  {\,\oalign{$\cdot$\cr\noalign{\kern-.3ex}%
    \hidewidth$\scriptscriptstyle#1$\hidewidth\cr}\,}}
\newcommand{\quaternary}[2]{\basex{4}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
$\quaternary{0}{t_1}$

$\basex{12}{0}{t_1}$
\end{document}
```

The `\basex` command is generic, so you can use different bases; saying `\quaternary{a}{b}` is equivalent to saying `\basex{4}{a}{b}`.

[image]

Using "official" LaTeX commands would be possible, but in cases like this one lower level commands are more flexible.

Comment: nice!  what if the base has more digits?  might that not tend to spread the arguments farther apart than desirable?

Comment: `\oalign` and `\noalign` together must be worth +1

Comment: @barbarabeeton I've added the needed `\hidewidth` commands; up to two digits show well, it seems.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it as

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\( 0_{\dot 4}t_1 \)

\( 0_{\dot{12}}t_1 \)

\( 0_{\dot{123}}t_1 \)
\end{document}
```

One can also shift the dot to left or right, if needed (which I have not done here).

[image]